# ec2 hostname static ip points to public dns and not the static ip postfix warning

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns, postfix-mta

I pointed A record to my new domain name as value of my elastic ip address but everytime i run

```
host XX.XX.XX.XX <- elastic ip
```

I get a result of:

XX.XX.XX.XX.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

Which is not my www.example.com registered domain, this leads to a postfix warning saying:

```
postfix/smtpd[12567]: warning: hostname ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com does not resolve to address XX.XX.XX.XX <-- elastic ip
```

Answer (score 0):

turned out i needed to reconfigure postfix by:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

then instead of ip-privateIP.us-west-2.compute.internal

type in your mail.example.com

Hope this would help someone in future, i have been scratching my head for the whole day